# how to test FBInstant.payments in browser?

Tags: facebook, facebook-instant-games, facebook-payments

I setup a test user to test `FBInstant.payments`for my instant game but it seems that even for test users it only work in Android? is there any way to test it on browser?

doesn't work even on `embedded mode`.

Even if CTRL+SHIFT+I is in mobile->Galaxy S5

`FBInstant.getPlatform();` it prints `WEB`.

is there any hack to test it on browser?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/instant-games/guides/in-app-purchases/

`Test transactions are only supported on Android at this time.`

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to test transactions on web without spending money. This is something that we will look to fix in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Chris.